# everytime I run playsound I get the same error

Tags: python, mp3, python-playsound

This is my code:

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound(r'C:\Users\owner\Downloads\BotW Item.mp3')
```

And this is the error I get:

[image: screenshot of my error]

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this: `r'C:\\Users\\owner\\Downloads\\BotW Item.mp3'` or just add one of them i.e like this: `r'C:\\Users\owner\Downloads\BotW Item.mp3'`. You have to escape the `\` character and the escape sequence for it in python is :`\\`.
If this doesn't work you can use os module:

```
import os
os.startfile('C:\\Users\\owner\\Downloads\\BotW Item.mp3')
```

Also regarding the playsound module, you should import it like this:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('C:\\Users\\owner\\Downloads\\BotW Item.mp3')
```

Comment: I edited the answer, see if any work for you